# Issue with fluent nhibernate TriggerIdentity in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, fluent-nhibernate, identity-column

When I tried to insert data into a table in SQL Server, which has an `ID` column specification as following, I'm getting the error,

> *Cannot insert NULL in RowID column*

even though I've written insert trigger for specifying the value of `RowID` column.

```
mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "RowID").GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();
```

Comment: is there a trigger on the table itself?

Comment: Yes, I've created a Trigger on insert in the database, to specify the RowID column's value

Comment: is it an "after trigger" or instead 'of trigger"?

Comment: It is not an after trigger. It is a "FOR INSERT" trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a FOR trigger; this is a different way of specifying an AFTER trigger. And you need to switch this to an "INSTEAD OF" trigger.Please refer to this [webpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175943%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

The reason it is failing now is because SQL Server validation is occurring prior to your trigger executing and performing it's primary key creation.